Candy and Tim share a paper route. It takes Candy $70$ min to deliver all the papers, while Tim takes $80$ min to deliver all the papers.
Candy and Tim share a paper route. It takes Candy $70$ min to deliver all the papers, while Tim takes $80$ min to deliver all the papers. How long would it take them if they work together?
The answer is apparently $\dfrac{1}{70}+\dfrac{1}{80}=\dfrac{1}{x}$
Here's what I don't understand. What does $\dfrac{1}{70}$ stand for? The rate of what? We don't know how many papers there are in total; we only know how long it takes them each to finish the route. So how can there be a rate based on one variable? For example rate of speed has two variables: distance over time.

Compute the rate at which each delivers papers. Assuming that they deliver to different people, the rate at which the deliver is the sum of the rates.

How many papers does Candy deliver in $~1~$ minute?

Apparently, the problem did not take into consideration the distance needed to travel or the speed of the two individuals.
The problem is supposed to just ask for the following reasoning:

In a single minute, Candy is able to deliver $1/70$ of all the papers. Similarly, in a single minute, Tim is able to deliver $1/80$ of all the papers. Notice that these quantities are additive now.
Therefore, if they work together, in a single minute, they are able to deliver $1/70 + 1/80 = 3/112$ of all the papers.
Thus, if they work together, the total number of minutes it will take for them to finish the work is $\boxed{112/3}$.


What do you mean they are additive? Thanks.

I precisely mean the second item. At that point, we are able to add those two quantities to find the amount they would be able to deliver if they worked together

If in a single minute their work is $\frac{3}{112}$, why do you flip the fraction to get the total amount of minutes?

It is due to the fact that the amount of work done is directly proportional to the number of minutes worked. Once we find that in $1$ minute the amount of work done is $3/112$, to find the total number of minutes to finish the whole work, we argue as follows. Let $x$ be the number of minutes necessary for the whole work to be completed. By direct proportionality, as in $1$ minute they are able to do $3/112$ amount of the work, in $x$ minutes they would be able to do $x\cdot3/112$ of the work. We want to find the $x$ for which $x\cdot3/112=1$ (i.e., the whole work), hence $x=112/3$
